# How do I flip a camera and not UI for a networked game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

This is my first networking game. I am trying to figure out how I position the player.  My Player is a building, so it doesn't move, but it dictates the game. Like a Tower Defense.  I always want the player to be at the bottom.

What I need is for isLocalPlayer to be at the bottom and the !isLocalPlayer at the top.  I have a working networked game running.  I have P1 at the bottom and P2 at the top.  But this appears on both screens.  Somehow I have to rotate the game object they are in for player 2?

Something like

```
if(Player2){
rotate game
}
```

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the unity3d documentation you can find in the networking namespace the NetworkStartPosition script

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkStartPosition.html

you have to attach this script and customize it on the player prefab and the non-player prefab, if you are asking about network item spaw you can look her :

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetSpawning.html

and if you are interested about other network management information you have a lot of information on the documentation, and some tutorials (I've tried them and they're actually working)

Edit :

if you just want each player to see something different you can use this tutorial :

https://unity3d.com/fr/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking/identifying-local-player?playlist=29690

it explain how to "work" with the local player only, have you seen it?

Comment: Thanks.  I have the NetworkStartPosition system working.  In the first image.  Player 1 is on the bottom and Player 2 is at the top.  This appears on both screens.  What I need is for Player 2 to be on the bottom and Player 1 to be on top as the view for Player 2.  It is like the whole thing needs to rotate.